# stop-computer fails to work suddenly

Tags: windows-10, powershell

powershell `stop-computer` cmdlet suddenly stops to work, even in administrator shell:

```
PS C:\> Stop-Computer
Stop-Computer : Privilege not held.
At line:1 char:1
+ Stop-Computer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (fluter-s:String) [Stop-Computer], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : StopComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopComputerCommand
```

It used to work with non-administrator shell, because surely a normal user can shutdown the system. There isn't a system update either.

Version info:

```
PS C:\> echo $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1066
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.1066
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have to be the result of a bug in one of OS updates. See more: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020459/after-you-apply-april-2017-security-updates-from-cve-2017-0160

From site:
**Workaround**

To work around this issue, run the following “shutdown.exe” command to execute power-down and restart operations on local or remote systems:

```
shutdown.exe [-r] [-s] [-m \\computer]
```

For more information and command help, run:

```
shutdown.exe -?
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on your answer, probably by explaining the workaround in-depth, instead of just linking to it?